# How to set up login pin system

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, xamarin

i want to set up basic login page in xamarin.forms. There is no username/password, just a simple pin

**so far i have 3 pages to do this**

- Sign-up Pin page
- Sign-up Confirm Pin Page (re-enter pin to confirm)
- Sign-in Pin Page
- Main app page

**my project flow as follows:**

- 1st time user, will be prompt to "Sign-up Pin Page", than "Sign-up Confirm Pin Page", than "Main app page"
- user that already have created a PIN, will be prompt to "Sign-in Pin Page", than "Main App Page.

**issue is that** "Sign-up Pin Page", "Sign-up Confirm Pin Page", and "Sign-in Pin Page" all have the same view, other than a label. 95% of the code is same. so if i make a small change like change color, than i will have to do in 3 different pages

my question is, is there better way to do this. should I use just one page to handle 3 pages? and do if/else to see which stage of flow user is in?

Comment: An age-old question. My advice, try it. This is a very small example, see what happens when you share the page, what do you have to do to make it handle each case. Sometimes it's a great thing to do. Other times it makes the page too complicated.

Comment: make a user control for the pin pad and use it on three pages

Comment: @Ewan, thanks. I mostly have pin-pad logic code & UI code. that is beeing reuseable. i will look into how can i make this into library or re-use able code